# How to get the ID of the last open bootstrap modal dialog in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to load the ID of the latest modal dialog I've opened inside a hidden field. How can I do this?
Here's my function:

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '#modalFileUpload, #modalFileUpload, #SadlModal, #PlanModal, #StatusModal', function () {
    $('#hid_ActiveDialogID').val('IDOFCURRENTLYOPENMODALHERE');
    $(this).keyup(function (e) {
        var modalFooter = $("#" + $('#hid_ActiveDialogID').val());
        var btnSave = $("#" + $('#hid_ActiveDialogID').val() + " div.modal-footer").children().first();

        if (e.which === 13) //enter
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (modalFooter.is(":visible")) {
                modalFooter.children().first().focus();
                btnSave.trigger('click');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This is the specific line of code I'm targeting with this question:

```
$('#hid_ActiveDialogID').val('IDOFCURRENTLYOPENMODALHERE');
```

Comment: use `$(this).attr("id")`

Comment: @Alexander Hristov, there is a difference between the last opened (as the title says) and the currently opened model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the currently active modal (assuming it's one of the id's on line 1 of your snippet), just use:

```
$('#hid_ActiveDialogID').val($(this).attr("id"));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks this helped me a lot!